# R rank data.frame in different categories

Tags: r, dataframe, rank

I am trying to rank dates in a date.frame, where duplicates get the same rank. Furhter I would like to distinguish between different categories. I did not use the rank function because I got floats as result.

My code is working but terribly slow.

How can I make this faster?

```
for(i in 1:length(unique_IDS)){
 temp_df=data.frame(rounds=unique(df$Dates[rounds$ID==unique_IDS[i]]), round_number=0)
 temp_df=temp_df[order(temp_df$rounds),]
 #temp_df$round_number=1:nrow(temp_df)
 df$round_number[df$ID==unique_IDS[i]]= match(x = df$Dates[df$ID==unique_IDS[i]],table=temp_df$rounds)
```

}

Best Regards

Comment: Try to make your question reproducible and provide desired output.

Answer (score 0):

this is an example of the code

```
df=data.frame(x=runif(10, 1, 10), cat="A", stringsAsFactors = F)
df$cat[3:5]="B"
df$cat[6:10]="C"

df$rank=0
cats=unique(df$cat)

for(i in 1:length(cats)){
     temp=df$x[df$cat==cats[i]]    
     temp=temp[order(temp)]     
     df$rank[df$cat==cats[i]]=match(df$x[df$cat==cats[i]], table = temp)
}

df
```

Best